# Is it possible to specify image used in steps according to the matrix strategy?

Tags: github-actions

I'm going to setup a workflow on GitHub which uses some docker images to check my package on different platform. I'd like to use the matrix strategy. Then I wrote a workflow like this:

```yaml
name: Main Workflow
on: [push]
jobs:
  test_linux:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        image: [ubuntu, fedora]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Test
        uses: docker://${{ matrix.image }}:latest
        with:
          entrypoint: /bin/bash
          args: ./test.sh
```

This is just a demo workflow. The real one is much more complicated.

However, after I pushed it, GitHub gave me the following error message:

> **Invalid workflow file: .github/workflows/main.yml#L16**
>
> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 13, Col: 15): Unrecognized named-value: 'matrix'. Located at position 1 within expression: matrix.image

Actually, I got this error instantly when I pushed codes.

Why? Is the matrix context inaccessible when parsing workflow file? Are there some ways to resolve it?

I tried to export the full docker name to environment in the previous step before "Test", but context `env` is also inaccessible just like the context `matrix`. I got nearly the same error. The only different is:

> Unrecognized named-value: 'env'...

Now I have to call `docker run` manually in run scripts like

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Test
    run: docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/code --workdir=/code ${{ matrix.image }}:latest /bin/bash -c "/code/test.sh"
```

It did work but I still prefer to use the `uses` entry.